# Transpose rows into columns in SQL Server, I try it using pivot but, expected result is not reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

Transpose rows into columns in SQL Server, I try it using pivot but, expected result is not reached, using pivot getting Max value only

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [patientid] [int] NULL,
    [sourcename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [identifier] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'SIN', N'2663563')
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'SIN', N'2453433')
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'MED', N'534545')
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'MED', N'212334')
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'NXG', N'8678')
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([patientid], [sourcename], [identifier]) 
VALUES (100, N'NXG', N'2131232334')
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select partitionid,
       max(case when sourcename = 'SIN' then identifier end) as sin,
       max(case when sourcename = 'MED' then identifier end) as med,
       max(case when sourcename = 'NXG' then identifier end) as nxg
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by partitionid, sourcename order by identifier) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by partitionid, seqnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select patientid,
    max(case when sourcename = 'SIN' then identifier end) as sin,
    max(case when sourcename = 'MED' then identifier end) as med,
    max(case when sourcename = 'NXG' then identifier end) as nxg
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by sourcename, sourcename order by identifier) rn
    from test t
) t
group by patientid, rn
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, thank you for quick response, the query what you shared, getting only one  row, could you pls see attached expected result set

Comment: @Yugandhar: please make sure to run the query exactly as provided.